# On Node.js v 8.9.3 the method Array.concat on extended class remove empty values - Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am trying to add some new power to `Arrays` into node.js without changing the `Array` class avoiding some unexpected impacts into others modules.

When I start testing my code, I found some failures that I finally could find the reason. The `concat` method behaves differently after extended.

This is completely strange to me. This is an expected behavior?

Very short version to see the problem:

```js
class MyArray extends Array{};

/*
 * Test with values
 */
var sizeValueArray = new Array(4,4,4).concat([1,2,3]).length;
var sizeValueMyArray = new MyArray(4,4,4).concat([1,2,3]).length;
console.log( "size from concat values array = ", sizeValueArray );
console.log( "size from concat values my array = ", sizeValueMyArray );
if( sizeValueArray != sizeValueMyArray ) {
  console.log("this is strange");
} else {
  console.log("as expected.")
}

/*
 * Test with empty values
 */
var sizeEmptyArray = new Array(5).concat(new Array(6) ).length;
var sizeEmptyMyArray = new MyArray(5).concat(new MyArray(6) ).length;
console.log( "size from concat empty array = ", sizeEmptyArray);
console.log( "size from concat empty my array = ", sizeEmptyMyArray );
if( sizeEmptyMyArray != sizeEmptyArray ) {
  console.log("this is strange");
} else {
  console.log("as expected.")
}
```

You can see that in the browser, the result of this two operations is the same. But not in the node.js, as you can see here https://repl.it/@thiagodamata/ArrayConcatStrangeBehaviorOnExtend

[image]

Comment: It's a bug, please report it. The [spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-array.prototype.concat) even explicitly notes "*The explicit setting of the `length` property in step 6 is necessary to ensure that its value is correct in situations where the trailing elements of the result Array are not present.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this bug was fixed in the recent versions. 
You can see that working in this [repl](https://repl.it/@thiagodamata/ArrayConcatStrangeBehaviorOnExtend).
So, it was a bug that is already fixed.